# Mobile App Design: Horizontal Swipe vs Vertical Scroll to browse recommended users

Tags: user-experience, mobile-application

I'm developing a mobile app that allows user to browse a list of other users that was defined by a recommender system. The app allows users to like, dislike or just view the profiles of other users. So, unlike to apps like Tinder, user can view profiles of other users more than once.
I doubt what is the best approach to design a navigation for this app. I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Horizontal swipe between users in a Tinder style
2. Vertical scroll of users list

The reason why I don't think that the first approach is the best one is that my app is not a dating app like Tinder, it's more an app where user can find a people with shared interests. User doesn't make a decision using only a photo of other user, there are more information that should be taken in concern.
So, using the vertical scroll will allow user to see more content and more easily navigate between recommended users. On the other hand, horizontal swipe is quite a common approach will help user to see more details about other users profiles.

Did I miss some of the pros and cons of the both solutions? Which approach is the best for my purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to put it in this way. 
Tidner started revolution in terms of horizontal swiping. And right after us Tinder become the Thing, lot of copy-cats started to use "one-card-horizontal-swipe-cards".

In that time that was cool. Tinder did amazing thing terms of showing content only one time on the one card per user. For Tinder this works amazing.

In terms of your app. 
If you want to present more than 1 user at the time, go with the vertical list. 
If you want to have "bird-eye-view", go with the vertical list.
If you want to scale your app, go with the vertical list.

I'm not familiar with your product, but base on your description, you should avoid horizontal swipe.

Also, allowing users to switch between horizontal and vertical view could be good option in terms of A/B testing.

Best,
R

EDIT: 
If you want to present those users as "recommended" as a object on the screen (e.g. User click on someone's profile, and at the bottom user is able to see suggestions) you should use horizontal swipe. 
But keep in mind horizontal swipe should *not be consider* as a native human behavior in terms of interactions with mobile devices (not yet).

LinkedIn has a good solution for profile recommendations (vertical swiping). You should explore it as well.